# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'

Tags: android, android-studio, context, android-toast

Есть 2 класса. В 1-классе вызываю метод 2-класса. И ошибка:

```
06-25 10:26:50.207 10459-10459/com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget, PID: 10459
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
                                                                                   at com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.fragments.ContentFragment.FAB_clear_method(ContentFragment.java:261)
                                                                                   at com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:69)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2908)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:206)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:776)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:959)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Код метода:

```
 public void FAB_clear_method(){
    LayoutOfScroll.removeAllViews();    //Удаление всех EditText стоимостей и наименований
    Budget = 0;                         //Обнуляю переменную Budget
    edBudget.setText("");               //Очищаю значение Бюджета
    Zatrati = 0;                        //Обнуляю переменную Zatrati
    tvZatrati.setText("0");             //Устанавливаю в "Затраты" значение "0"
    Ostatok = 0;                        //Обнуляю переменную Ostatok
    tvOstatok.setText("0");             //Устанавливаю в "Остаток" значение "0"
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Очищено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         //Тост очистки всех данных и товаров
}
```

Код вызова метода:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_item_clear:
            ContentFragment object = new ContentFragment();
            object.FAB_clear_method();
```

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите дурацкие комментарии в коде вида `Budget = 0; // обнуляю переменную Budget`.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте про жизненный цикл фрагментов.

Нельзя просто создать фрагмент, а потом сразу вызвать метод, который использует `Context`. Пока фрагмент не присоединен к активити, у него нет никакого контекста.
Т.е. вот здесь:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Очищено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`getContext()` возвращает `null`, поэтому и вылетает исключение.

Но суть проблемы здесь:

```
ContentFragment object = new ContentFragment();
object.FAB_clear_method();
```

Фрагмент висящий просто в памяти не может отображать `Toast`. Он должен быть отображен в контексте активити, тогда вы можете безопасно вызывать метод `FAB_clear_method()`